# Svelte JS: what is the purpose of the onDestroy implementation inside another method

Tags: javascript, components, svelte, ondestroy

I'm studying Svelte JS. In this [REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/8e68120858e5322272dc9136c4bb79cc?version=3.5.1) and wonder to know what is the purpose of the `onDestroy` method added in the definition of the component `Tabs`. I understand that it is the way to manage what happens when a component is destroyed but I've never seen it defined inside another method.

```
tab => {
        tabs.push(tab);
        selectedTab.update(current => current || tab);

        onDestroy(() => {
            const i = tabs.indexOf(tab);
            tabs.splice(i, 1);
            selectedTab.update(current => current === tab ? (tabs[i] || tabs[tabs.length - 1]) : current);
        });
    },
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is one simple rule with lifecycle functions like `onDestroy`: they have to be called during component init, that is they must be called synchronously in the component's `<script>` tag.

```
<script>
  import { onDestroy } from 'svelte'

  onDestroy(..) // ok

  {
    onDestroy(..) // ok
  }

  (() => {
    onDestroy(..) // ok
  })()

  const fn = callback => {
    onDestroy(callback)
  }

  fn() // ok

  setTimeout(() => {
    onDestroy(..) // NOT OK !!!
    fn() // NOT OK
  })
</script>
```

What's important is when the call is made, not where in the code it is located. The lifecycle callback will be attached to the component currently being initialized, wherever the call comes from.

You can put `onDestroy` in a function if you want, that just means that the user of this function will have to call it during the init of a component, and the callback will run when *this* component is destroyed.

In the example you've linked, the context is used as a transport for the function that contains `onDestroy`. Context also have to be resolved synchronously during the init phase of a component, so we're good. The component gets the function from the context, it calls it immediately, and the function can register some cleanup on the component without the component knowing. That's nice encapsulation.

Comment: thanks for the answer, it answered perfectly my question. And yes, I think too it is a nice encapsulation :)

Answer (score 0):

Calling `onDestroy` adds a callback that will be called when the svelte component is destroyed. You can add as many callbacks as you want and call the method whenever you want.

Here, it looks like the developer wanted different cleanup routines for different contexts.

Comment: Thanks for the answer!
But this `onDestroy` is inside a function which is itself inside a `setContext`.
Does it mean that whereever you implement `onDestroy`, it will always be played by the component which uses the parent function?